# banco de dados Mysql remoto lento com aplicação java swing

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, swing

Tenho uma aplicação java swing que está conectada com um banco de dados Mysql remoto, ou seja, em um servidor online.

Quando executo o programa ele funciona normal, exceto pela lentidão nas resposta do banco. Por exemplo, eu abro a janela de cadastro de usuários e ele demora cerca de 20 segundos para abrir. esse problema não acontecia quando estava com o banco local.

Aqui o código que faz conexão com o banco:

```
public java.sql.Connection conectaBanco() {
    Connection conn = null; //pro compilador ficar feliz
    try {
        // Carrega o driver JDBC 
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
        Class.forName(driverName);
        System.out.println("ok");
        // Configuração da conexão com um Conexao1 de dados//
        //troque por seu ip, senha, user, etc
        String serverName = "aqui vai o server onde o banco está";

        //caminho do servidor do BD - para acesso local coloque : localhost
        String mydatabase ="nome_do_banco";        //nome do seu banco de dados 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;
        System.out.println("ok");
        String user = "nome_do_usuario";        //nome de um usuário de seu BD      
        String key = "senha";      //sua senha de acesso 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, key);
        //Testa sua conexão//
        System.out.println("Conectado!");
        return conn; 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  //Driver não encontrado 
        System.out.println("O driver expecificado nao foi encontrado.");                
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //Não conseguindo se conectar ao Conexao1
        System.out.println("Nao foi possivel conectar ao Banco de Dados.");            
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Uma das consultas:

SELECT * FROM Nome_Da_Tabela

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow Filipe! Sugiro que você inclua o trecho do código que faz a requisição ao banco de dados - ele dará uma idéia melhor pro pessoal do que está ocorrendo! :)

Comment: editei o post, por favor, olhem ele.

Comment: Geralmente demora um pouco mais mesmo, localmente é bem mais rápido, qual o servidor que seu banco está hospedado?
Você poderia postar essa consulta que demora 20 segundos?

Comment: +1 pro @RafaelFerreira - Tirando a pergunta do servidor, que é normalmente considerada informação confidencial ;) - Inclua a consulta de 20 segundos, pois é provavelmente onde está o problema.

Comment: Olha, o servidor que estou usando é o hostgator. Enquanto a consulta, são todas elas! Qualquer coisa que eu faça demora de 15 a 30 segundos! Coloquei uma consulta simples de SELECT aí em cima.

Comment: vc está fazendo consultas via linq ou lambda?

Answer (score 4):

Com as informações que você nos passou até o momento, infelizmente não é possível encontrar um **"culpado"** para as suas requisições de 15 segundos.

Entretanto, podemos listar algumas idéias básicas que devem ser consideradas ao mover um aplicativo local para a `web`:

---

- **Quantas requisições o aplicativo está fazendo?**

É importante lembrar que na internet as coisas são **infinitamente** mais lentas do que localmente. Na maioria das conexões, os dados precisam ser enviados, e precisam ter sua recepção confirmada. Não é a toa que são removidos espaços em branco de páginas `HTML` e documentos `CSS` - cada `byte` importa.

*Reduza o número de requisições o máximo que puder.*

- **Qual o tamanho da requisição sendo feita?**

É muito fácil cometermos o erro de pedir registros desnecessários de um banco e com isso aumentarmos enormemente o tráfego de dados na rede.

*Utilize as ferramentas que o `SQL` disponibiliza, e faça requisições que retornem **exatamente** a informação que você precisa. Não trate dados recebidos de bancos no seu aplicativo. Os bancos são construídos para isso e são muito bons no que fazem.*

- **As requisições são *"blocking"*?**

Essa é uma idéia importante para aplicativos online que é fácil deixar passar quando se trabalha local. Um aplicativo que espera uma requisição de banco de dados retornar para carregar janelas/menus/etc., prejudica bastante a experiência do usuário.

*Tente colocar tarefas demoradas em processos separados, e lembre de avisar o usuário que algo está acontecendo em segundo plano.*

---

Se você já tem essas idéias implementadas, eu sugiro que você faça uma conexão por `prompt de comando` com o seu banco de dados remoto e verifique o tempo que leva para conectar e fazer requisições.

Se a conexão for muito mais rápida, talvez valha incluir o resto do seu código para que o pessoal dê uma olhada.

Se for lenta igual, eu levaria essa questão ao serviço de hospedagem e consideraria a mudança de serviço.

**Atenção:** Considere a quantidade de registros que você possui no banco - um `SELECT * FROM Tabela` como no seu exemplo, se utilizado num banco como o do facebook, pode simplesmente **nunca retornar**.

*PS. Quando eu pedi o código, me referia ao que engloba a declaração SQL, e não à declaração em si.*